# Opencv video writer only writes 128byte files (os x el capitan)

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

So i tried several pieces of code now, all more or less similar, and they all only produce a 128 byte file. I want to record the webcam stream to file.

I don't believe this is a codec issue, i tried all of them and i still get only 128 bytes. Anyone know what the problem here is ? So far i only tried it on MacOS X.

For example below code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
CvCapture* capture;

capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

assert( capture != NULL );

IplImage* bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

CvSize size = cvSize(
                     (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture,
                                               CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                     (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture,
                                               CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
                     );

cvNamedWindow( "Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(    "vidtry.AVI",
                                            CV_FOURCC('A','V','C','1'),
                                            30,
                                        size
                                            );

while( (bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture )) != NULL ) 
{
     cvWriteFrame(writer, bgr_frame );
     cvShowImage( "Webcam", bgr_frame );
     char c = cvWaitKey( 33 );
     if( c == 27 ) break;
}
cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "Webcam" );
return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: try different codecs like mjpg and make sure that the opencv_ffmpeg dll is available to the application

Comment: I tried pretty much every codec. Why do I need the dll (i'm on mac btw). I'd rather avoid using ffmpeg if I can. Anyone?

Comment: on windows, opencv uses ffmpeg internally and provides a special dll. If the dll is not present, videowriter just creates a (nearly) empty file without any error. Not sure how it is handled on osx.

Comment: Thanks Micka. Is there any way of writing a video without using ffmpeg?

Comment: With opencv functions? I dont think so, but no guarantee.